# Mapping servlet in web.xml

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

The xml file is located in `WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml` of my project. I am using Eclipse and running Tomcat (which is not installed via Eclipse. I prefer it to be a separate installation).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>EmployeeManagement</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>name</param-name>
    <param-value>Pramod</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/EmployeeManagement/WebContent/Registration</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

It doesnt work when the form page submits to the servlet. I am getting a 404 error everytime. I have been encountering this problem for a while. Somebody please help me.

Comment: Post your `form action`.

Comment: I can't see Servlet tag in your web.xml

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing `<servlet>...</servlet>` tag which is important to mapping. So use following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>EmployeeManagement</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
    <param-name>name</param-name>
    <param-value>Pramod</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.yourPackageName.yourServletName</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/EmployeeManagement/WebContent/Registration</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and you should give `action` value on your form like following:

```
<form action="/EmployeeManagement/WebContent/Registration" method="post">

      //Some code here

</form>
```

and also note it down all values are case sensitive on the following code:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.yourPackageName.yourServletName</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/EmployeeManagement/WebContent/Registration</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Your servlet name `Registration` should be same on both tags `<servlet>...</servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>...</servlet-mapping>` and also `package` name should be same where your servlet class is located.

Comment: where can i find servlet-name and url-pattern for configuring web.xml

Answer (score 2):

you have not mapped servlet name to servlet class, It should be like given below,

In  `<servlet-class>` give the path of your servlet

```
    <servlet>
         <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>com.Registration<servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/EmployeeManagement/WebContent/Registration</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your form action.
Is the path there

```
/EmployeeManagement/WebContent/Registration
```

or

```
YOURAPPCONTEXT/EmployeeManagement/WebContent/Registration
```

or

```
YOURAPPNAME/EmployeeManagement/WebContent/Registration
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a vital part of the configuration. You should add this to your `web.xml` before `servlet-mapping` tag:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.name.of.your.servlet.class</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have specifyed a `servlet-mapping` and used the name `Registration` in `servlet-name` without defining it before.

You need to define the servlet before using it in a servlet mapping

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>[fully qualifyied name of your servlet]</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing another part to define the servlet in the web.xml

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>
      package.path.to.RegistrationServlet
  </servlet-class>
</servlet>
```