# How to redirect from one servlet to another?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm accepting first name from html page and displaying it in "firstservlet" class. And in first servlet class, i'm trying to accept last name by creating html textbox and redirect to "secondservlet" class where i can display both first name and last name. But i'm getting 404 error. How to resolve this error.

FirstServlet.java

```
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");  
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

   HttpSession session=request.getSession();
    out.println(session.isNew());

    String name=request.getParameter("FirstName");

    request.setAttribute("name", name);

    out.println("First name is " +name);

    out.print("\n");
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<form action=SecondServlet/>");
    out.println("Enter LastName<input type=text name=LastName>");
    out.println("<br>");
    out.println("<input type=submit />");
    out.println("</form>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");

    String lname=request.getParameter("LastName");

    request.setAttribute("lname", lname);

    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("SecondServlet");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

SecondServlet.java

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");  

    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

    String name=request.getParameter("FirstName");
    request.setAttribute("name", name);
    out.println("First name is " +name);

    out.println("<br>");

    String lname=request.getParameter("LastName");      
    request.setAttribute("name", lname);
    out.println("Last name is " +lname);

    out.println("<br>");
```

}

Comment: Please show us `web.xml`. Also, note that `getRequestDispatcher` requires a URL (relative to server root) and not a servlet name or class name.

Comment: Haven't made any changes to web.xml apart from setting my html as homepage. and i have only one html page

Comment: That would be the issue. You need to add the second servlet to the web.xml.

Comment: <welcome-file>NewFile.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>    Where should i add it?

Comment: You need to add a servlet and a servlet mapping. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889681/mapping-servlet-in-web-xml.

Comment: or can i just add      response.sendRedirect("SecondServlet");??