# Any way of mapping java servlet using simple regex?

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, servlet-mapping

I need to map `/Test` to a servlet Test.java and also `/anything/Test` to the same servlet. I read that `/*/Test` won't work in web.xml as it doesn't accept regex.

Is there any alternate way of doing it using filters ? I can't use Tuckey URL filter due to some blockage issue. Also, I need that "anything" also in my servlet. I planned to process the url string for that if I am able to map.

For example

`/ProjectName/Test`
Should open Test servlet

and also `/ProjectName/xyz/Test`
Should also open Test servlet

Now xyz can be anything. And I also want to get xyz in my Test servlet. I planned to get xyz in by `request.getRequestURI()` and fetching it from the url.

Comment: Improve your question, it is unclear what you are asking!

Comment: I did. Gave a example

Comment: Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889681/mapping-servlet-in-web-xml) helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a filter.

This one is a basic one that should work.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

    String url = req.getRequestURI();
    if (url.endsWith("test")) {
        request.getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher("TestServlet").forward(request, response);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Key points. I use `getNamedDispatcher` to get the named servlet you wish to use. It's probably best to not actually map this servlet to a pattern at all.

By using the `getNamedDispatcher`, it does not corrupt the request url within the destination servlet proper.

Comment: Exaclty what I wanted. Thank you