# Servlet mapping in web Applications

Tags: java, xml, servlets, web

Currently I'm working for web application. Actually my code looks like below

```
<div class="article">
                                    <form action="currentcondition.do" method="post">
                                        <table>
                                            <tr><td>Disease Name</td><td><input type="text" name="disease" required/></td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Status</td><td><select name="status"><option>-Select-</option>
                                                        <option>Current : Currently has this</option>
                                                        <option>Intermittent : Comes and Goes</option>
                                                        <option>Past : No longer has this</option>
                                                    </select> </td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Start Date</td><td><input type="date" name="sdate"/></td><td>End Date</td><td><input type="date" name="edate"/></td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Hospital Name</td><td><input type="text" name="hname" /></td><td>Dr Phone</td><td><input type="text" name="dphone"  maxLength="10"/></td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Note</td><td><textarea name="note"></textarea></td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Click here to</td><td><input type="submit" value="save"/></td></tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </form>
                </div>
```

here calling action as **currentcundition.do**. I think this is servlet program which naming as **currentcondition.java**. how to map this servlet program to my web application. please help I'm stuck here

This is my servlet code it named as `currentcundition.java`

```
@WebServlet(name = "currentcondition", urlPatterns = {"/currentcondition.do"})
public class currentcondition extends HttpServlet {
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {

            String disease= request.getParameter("disease");            
            String abedisease= attributebasedencryption.getattributebasedencryptionInstance().stringToHex(disease);
            request.setAttribute("abedisease", abedisease);
            RequestDispatcher go = request.getRequestDispatcher("/savecurrentcondition.jsp");
            go.forward(request, response);
        }
```

**Edit**:

my web.xml code

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PHP</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.controller.currentcondition</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PHP</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/PHP/currentcondition.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It is not showing what what I'm expecting. please guide me

Comment: Please refer to the below answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18889931/3270795 Hope this helps.

Comment: I have Edited my question, Now please guide me

Answer (score 0):

If you could use annotations like this

```
 @WebServlet("/loginServlet")
 public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
       //your code
}
```

on your servlet code, then you can directly define the action="loginServlet"

Comment: see my edit in my question section and please let me know what I need to do

Comment: dont you have a get post methods overridden..? and just use the urlPatterns = {"/currentcondition"} remove the do part in the form as well, they will forwarded to the right methods automatically

Comment: I did not get you what you saying

Comment: put this to servelt annotation urlPatterns = {"/currentcondition.do"} and change the form action accordingly without ".do" part. in servlet override the doPost method so that it can handle POST requests

Comment: I have Edited my question, Now please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be in  `doPost` instead of `processRequest` method, as `doPost` will be called because you are using `method="post"` in your form.